# Adding Custom Slider

Tags: php, jquery

I having a few issues adding code to functions.php to implement a custom slider. The code is below. I'm struggling to find out what I am doing wrong.

```
// Slick Slider

wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/js/slick.min.js'), true);
wp_enqueue_style( 'slick', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/slick.css', array(), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/css/slick.css'), false );
wp_enqueue_style( 'slick-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/slick-theme.css', array(), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/css/slick-theme.css'), false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );


// Add slick slider to homepage

function home_slider_init() {
    if (is_front_page()) {
        ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('.home-slider').slick({
                dots: true,
                arrows: true,
                prevArrow: '.home-slider__prev',
                nextArrow: '.home-slider__next',
                autoplay: false,
                lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
            });

        });
    </script>
<?php
}
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'home_slider_init');
```

Comment: You need to explain your problem.  What is working.  What isn't working.  Have you debugged?